# Databricks Sql: Alternative to NCHAR() to replace characters

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have names in my table for which I need to replace certain characters with others.
I have the following code, but I get an error

`REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(name),NCHAR(0x2019),NCHAR(0x0027)),NCHAR(0x200B),'')`

However I get the following error message. Can somebody help me rewrite the code not using the Nchar function?

> Undefined function: 'NCHAR'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `NCHAR` function you can use unicode literals (`\uXXXX`) to represent a character as it's described in [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html#string-literal), in your case it will be:

```sql
REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(name),'\u2019','\u0027'),'\u200B','')
```